# Spring Boot - nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type '' available

Tags: spring-boot, maven, annotations, autowired

I'm trying to add the following statement to a Spring Boot service:

```
@Autowired 
private ApELDatabasePublisherService eventPublisher;
```

The dependency for eventPublisher is contained in maven, in this jar file:

```
.m2\repository\com\xxxx\bip\bip-event-logging\1.5.3.7-RELEASE.jar
```

It compiles, builds and updates the local maven repository, but when I launch the application, it terminates with an error message.

Initially, the error message was this:

```
No qualifying bean of type 'com.xxxx.bip.components.el.services.ApELDatabasePublisherService' available
```

However, that disappeared when I added `com.xxxx.bip.components.el.services` to the component scan.

The next message was this:

```
No qualifying bean of type 'com.xxxx.bip.components.el.dao.services.IApElTypeNameLookupService' available:
```

So I added `com.xxxx.bip.components.el.dao.services` to the component scan, and that error went away.

But now I have a third message which is not going away, as follows:

```
No qualifying bean of type 'com.xxxx.bip.components.el.repository.IApELEventTypeRepository' available
```

This message stays even when I add the following to component scan:

```
com.xxxx.bip.components.el.repository
```

So my current scan looks like this:

```
@EnableRetry
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "com.xxxx.bip.components.el.services",
        "com.xxxx.bip.components.el.dao.services",
        "com.xxxx.bip.components.el.repository",
```

I've verified that the class in question, `IApELEventTypeRepository` is included in the jar file and is annotated as "@Repository"

Why would it not find it when it finds the previous two packages?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with the repositories/entites located in the another package than spring application, it can't find repositories in order to make a default implementations for them.

Try to add to your configuration

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="<repository package name>")
```

And most probably, you will need to add annotation, so that Spring can find entities.

```
@EntityScan("packages")
```